# How to calculate or estimate floating point rounding error for a specific number

Tags: floating-point, rounding, computer-science, precision, ieee-754

I'm converting 64 bit numbers to 32 bit numbers and in doing the conversion I want to ensure that my numbers only get bigger in the conversion and not smaller. I know that the rounding error for numbers gets larger as numbers get larger but I would like to expand the number being converted by the rounding error for the number to ensure it doesn't get rounded down.

Here is how I'm currently estimating the rounding error (in javascript), which works, but I'm wondering if there's a better way:

```js
const error = x * Math.pow( 2, -24 );
```

To go into more detail about my use case I'm creating a bounding volume hierarchy and storing the bounds that contain objects as a boxes center and half width (computed with 64 bit calculations). And when converting those numbers to 32 bit to store in a buffer they are rounded which can result in a bounding box that is smaller or "shifted" and does not fully contain the intended contents. I'm expanding the half extents by the estimated rounding error of both the center and the half extents values to accommodate.

So is there a way to accurately get the maximum floating point rounding error at some number scale? Is there a problem with the way I am estimating the number above?

Thank you!

Comment: I hope to address this a bit more later, but I will point out you want to add half an ULP of the 32-bit format into the 64-bit number before converting. If you add to the 32-bit result, you will have to add a full ULP to be sure if getting a larger result. Adding on the 64-bit side means you can use a finer adjustment, introducing less error.

Comment: Thanks for the response -- I'll look forward to a bit more detail but in the use case I outlined I am adding the estimated error for both the center and half extents to the 64 bit value: `halfExtents += ( halfExtents + center ) * Math.pow( 2, - 24 )`. ULP isn't a term I'd been familiar with but after looking it up it sounds like that's what I'm looking to calculate so advice on how to quickly and / or accurately calculate that for a number would be great.

Comment: For a binary32 number in [1, 2), the ULP is 2^-23. For any number in the normal range, the ratio is the same. The distance between any real number and the nearest representable number is at most ½ ULP. So the error in converting any number in the normal range to binary32 using round-to-nearest is at most ½ ULP. So the relative error must be in (½ ULP / 2, ½ ULP / 1] = (¼ ULP, ½ ULP] = (2^-25, 2^-24). So, if you increase the value of a number in the normal range by a relative amount of at least 2^-24, it cannot decrease by more than that when converted to binary32.

Comment: Therefore, converting x•(1+2^-24) to binary32 yields a number at least as large as x, unless it is in the subnormal range. Note there are additional considerations: If x is negative, do you want a number y at least as large as x in magnitude (|x| ≤ |y|) or a number at least as great as x (x < y)?

Comment: I am not ready to enter this as an answer because there are some things to consider. One is that multiplying x by 1+2^-24 in binary64 could round down. I suspect that, even if that occurs, the final result of conversion to binary32 will not exceed ½ ULP total error, but I would want to prove it (or find a counterexample and an alternative calculation) before entering an answer. Also, this just discusses converting one number from binary64 to binary32. You apparently have a center c and a half-width h, both binary64, and want to find binary32 c' and h' such that c'-h' ≤ c-h and c+h ≤ c'+h'.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. Your final statement about my center and half width values at the end is correct. It sounds like my assumptions about multiplying the values by the ULP is correct so I'm comfortable with what I've got at the moment. The base64 round down case is interesting though. I wouldn't expect that that would happen given that 64 bit floats have so much more precision but I'd be interested to know if it's possible. Thank you again!

Comment: Can the half-width ever be greater than the center coordinate (so the coordinate of the left/lower edge is negative)? If so, it is possible the half-width has a greater ULP than the center coordinate, which complicates things. In any case, I am thinking a reasonable solution is to convert the 64-bit center coordinate c to a 32-bit coordinate c', then compare c to c' to see which way it moved, if either. Also convert the 64-bit half-width h to 32-bit h'. Then compute either (c+h)-(c'+h') or (c−h)−(c'−h') see see how much h' has to be increased to compensate for rounding issues.

Comment: How to adjust h' then depends on the programming language. If control of rounding mode is available, one would simply evaluate h'=h'+x with rounding upward, where x is the required amount. Without control of rounding mode, one might evaluate h'+x+½u in 64-bit and convert the result to 32-bit, where u is the 32-bit ULP or an approximation of it.

Comment: Yes the half width can be larger. The bounds could be centered at 0 and the half width extends in the positive and negative direction to describe the full bounds. I think understand how to solve my problem now -- my question was primarily what the right way was to get the maximum error estimate for a particular number, which you've confirmed. My solution is to just take the magnitude of `c` and `h` and add the error to `h'` because it's faster than using `Math.fround` (javascript) and determining the exact difference and direction in values.